# Nushell table update works unless I set the result to a mutable variable

Tags: mutable, nushell

This code runs perfectly:

```
    $table | update col { |row| "some value" } | print
```

This code also runs perfectly:

```
    let $final_table = $table | update col { |row| "some value" }
    $final_table | print
```

This code throws a `Command does not support nothing` error on the call to `update`:

```
    $table = $table | update col { |row| "some value" }
    $table | print
```

The only difference in the last one is that `$table` (a mutable variable) is being set, instead of a newly created variable or just directly pipelining to the `print` command. Why would that make a difference to this code, erroring or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Nushell 0.83, declaration keywords such as `let` and `mut` no longer require the use of subexpressions to assign the output of a pipeline to a variable (see [blog](https://www.nushell.sh/blog/2023-07-25-nushell_0_83.html#declaration-and-assignment-of-variables)).

However, assigning the output of a pipeline to a mutable variable as you are doing in this case is an intentional exception to this language improvement.  For that, you'll still need to use subexpressions:

```bash
$table = ($table | update col "some value")
```

Note that I also simplified your `update` command here, as it only contained a static value.

Given the language improvement, this *could* also be done using the `let` or `mut` keywords.  For example:

```bash
let $final_table = $table | update col { |row| "some value" }
```

or

```bash
mut $table = $table | update col { |row| "some value" }
```

However, redeclaring (shadowing) the same variable is not a good practice. Best to continue to use subexpressions for this purpose, as demonstrated in the first example above.

Comment: That worked; thanks! It seems strange that the precedence would be different between those cases; do you know if that's the intended behavior vs a bug?

Comment: @neurodynamic I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I've appreciated this change, but it does bite me every now and then in exactly this type of situation.  I'm still trying to decide if it's better to just continue to use subexpressions in *all* cases to avoid having to treat the different use cases separately.  Right now, my code is a mix of "using subexpressions with `let` and `mut`" and vice-versa.  I think I'm leaning towards just continuing to use subexpressions in every case -- I'm not quite sure the syntactic sugar is worth the extra cognitive bandwidth, but I haven't quite decided yet :-)

Comment: If I may add my 2¢ as a non-developer: Syntax (esp. syntactic sugar) should always be either intuitive, i.e in strong coherence with other language design decisions, or the benefits of breaking it should evidently outweigh the issues that come along. Imho, this issue (as encountered) was clearly a matter of scope/precedence, but tracking it down to the "language improvement" actually causing it was not intuitive at all. Thus, looking at its benefits, it depends on how much Nu tries to attract/accomodate users coming from line-oriented/imperative languages with explicit declaration-only lines.